# building project with libcurl doesn't work under linux

Tags: c, linux, libcurl

i am attempting to build a little project in C under Linux in Eclipse Juno. As I include the libcurl library, I think the linker throw always the error cannot find -lcurl. I know there are several posts on the internet, but nothing really helps. The whole looks like this:

```
Building target: c_template
Invoking: GCC C Linker
/usr/local/oecore-i686-arm/sysroots/i686-oesdk-linux/usr/bin/armv7a-vfp-neon-oe-linux-gnueabi/arm-oe-linux-gnueabi-gcc -L/usr/lib --sysroot=/usr/local/oecore-i686-arm/sysroots/armv7a-vfp-neon-oe-linux-gnueabi -o  "c_template"  ./src/atCommand.o ./src/charDevice.o ./src/curl.o ./src/debug.o ./src/linux_prototype.o ./src/output.o ./src/simStatus.o ./src/urc.o ./src/wwan.o   -lpthread -lcurl
                 from <command-line>:0:
/home/ubuntu/Documents/eCall/hwell_06/workspace_hwell_06/c_template/inc/defs.h:87:10: warning: type defaults to 'int' in declaration of 'BOOL' [-Wimplicit-int]
/home/ubuntu/Documents/eCall/hwell_06/workspace_hwell_06/c_template/inc/atCommand.h:56:12: warning: 'atCommandsHandler' defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]
/home/ubuntu/Documents/eCall/hwell_06/workspace_hwell_06/c_template/inc/debug.h:60:12: warning: 'deviceHandler' defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]
/usr/local/oecore-i686-arm/sysroots/i686-oesdk-linux/usr/libexec/armv7a-vfp-neon-oe-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-oe-linux-gnueabi/4.6.3/ld: warning: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libpthread.so while searching for pthread
/usr/local/oecore-i686-arm/sysroots/i686-oesdk-linux/usr/libexec/armv7a-vfp-neon-oe-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-oe-linux-gnueabi/4.6.3/ld: warning: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libcurl.so while searching for curl
/usr/local/oecore-i686-arm/sysroots/i686-oesdk-linux/usr/libexec/armv7a-vfp-neon-oe-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-oe-linux-gnueabi/4.6.3/ld: error: cannot find -lcurl
/usr/local/oecore-i686-arm/sysroots/i686-oesdk-linux/usr/libexec/armv7a-vfp-neon-oe-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-oe-linux-gnueabi/4.6.3/ld: warning: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libc.so while searching for c
../src/curl.c:66: error: undefined reference to 'curl_global_init'
../src/curl.c:69: error: undefined reference to 'curl_easy_init'
../src/curl.c:72: error: undefined reference to 'curl_slist_append'
../src/curl.c:73: error: undefined reference to 'curl_slist_append'
../src/curl.c:76: error: undefined reference to 'curl_easy_setopt'
../src/curl.c:79: error: undefined reference to 'curl_easy_setopt'
../src/curl.c:82: error: undefined reference to 'curl_easy_setopt'
../src/curl.c:85: error: undefined reference to 'curl_easy_setopt'
../src/curl.c:98: error: undefined reference to 'curl_easy_perform'
../src/curl.c:101: error: undefined reference to 'curl_easy_strerror'
../src/curl.c:105: error: undefined reference to 'curl_slist_free_all'
../src/curl.c:108: error: undefined reference to 'curl_easy_cleanup'
../src/curl.c:112: error: undefined reference to 'curl_global_cleanup'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [c_template] Error 1
```

I already set up the paths for the library for the linker:
For the library search path (-L) : /usr/lib
and for libraries (-l): curl

My command line pattern looks like this:

${COMMAND} ${FLAGS} ${OUTPUT_FLAG} ${OUTPUT_PREFIX} ${OUTPUT} ${INPUTS}

Can anyone helps me. Would be great.

Thanks a lot

Comment: You need to cross-compile your own cURL library and use that. You can't use the hosts library unless host and arget systems are the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're crosscompiling `c_template` for ARM so you'll need to install the `libcurl` for ARM in your cross-compile environment. Right now it finds the `libcurl` for your i686 host and it cannot use that as shown in:

```
/usr/local/oecore-i686-arm/sysroots/i686-oesdk-linux/usr/libexec/armv7a-vfp-neon-oe-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-oe-linux-gnueabi/4.6.3/ld: warning: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libcurl.so while searching for curl
```

So first compile/install `libcurl` for your target platform in your compile environment and make sure your compiler can find that.

Comment: MMh, I was glad too early. Building the first time with the cross-compiled curl all was fine. But later, the same mistake occurs. I cross-compiled curl und told the linker the directories.

Comment: MMh, I was glad too early. Building the first time with the cross-compiled curl all was fine. But later, the same mistake occurs. I cross-compiled curl und told the linker the paths. 
In Library search path (-L) I put the path of the libraries /home/ubuntu/tools/lib and in Libraries (-l) curl.